# How to send bitcoin without any fees to different btc address?

Tags: transaction-fees

Now I am using regular client wallet to spend my btc amount. but it charges me miner fee, sometime it pretty high. I dont want to pay fees anymore.

My friend heard about a way to send btc without any fees. In this point my questions are:

1. what is the demerits if I want to send btc without fees?
2. And Finally, How could I send btc to different address without paying any fees?

Comment: Ok, I am going through the post details